# Is having a toggle on title bar okay for android app?

Tags: interaction-design, mobile-application, material-design

I am designing a mail interface, with an option to add an encryption.
One idea is to having the encryption as a toggle on the title bar. If the user turns on the toggle, he needs to enter password in a dialogue. If the user does not want to give password to this mail, just turn the toggle off.

Do you see any usability problems about this design?

[image]

Comment: Personally, I feel like it introduces more confusion since users should be expecting a setting to be in a settings menu. Also, how is this accessed? It would be a shame if anyone had access to the title bar and could turn it off.

Comment: I agree - nothing about that toggle says to me "if I flip this switch, I will be entering encrypted mode." That sort of control feels as if it should be somewhere in a more global settings area, unless it applies differently within the same mailbox or something.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, [Google Inbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.inbox&hl=en) already does something similar.

[image]

It seems odd if you think about it. However, Google is doing it for a reason. Here the toggle changes the view from mails to reminders. It is a quick action. If you notice there are two actions. Search and reminder toggle.

Personally, I am not a big fan of such a toggle, I'd rather put a selection/deselection kind of metaphor using the Material Design shadows, but I am not Google employee... ;)

If it gives you any comfort, the pioneers of material design have done exactly the same thing that you are trying to do. Hope that helps.

Comment: That's actually just what I had in mind with my answer below, but their toggle has a very clear purpose that is directly related to the view that the header sits on top of.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is fine to include a toggle in a title bar as long as it is very clear what that toggle does and what two states are represented. This is not the case in your sample, and from what you describe I think that option should be handled on a different screen.